# Easy way to implement responsive font sizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way of setting all font sizes to scale down x amount in a media query, instead of setting font size for each element ( h1, h2, h3 ).
Currently I have a media query that looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
  body {
   font-size: 20px;
  }  
}
```

This, however, doesn't set sizes for headings. Is there any way to include all text on a site? Thanks

Comment: Use root em `rem` for your headings. Check [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, basically you set font size in pixels for a root element like `html` and then you can use [rem](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/) units to set font sizes for other elements. In your @media rule you will have to change just `font-size` property for `html` element and it will equally affect other elements since they depend on root's font-size because you use `rem`s.

```
html {
    font-size: 12px;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.footer {
    font-size: .9rem;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    /* now the basis for all the font sizes set in
    rems is 10px. For example, font-size for p is 10*1.1 = 11px. 
    Previously it was 1.1*12 = 13.2px. */
    html {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{font-size:15px;}
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  div{font-size:20px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  div{font-size:25px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
  div{font-size:50px;}
}
```

```html
<div>test font size</div>
```